# Using a custom class with a custom template container

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to define a custom template container, and then add custom class objects (Students) into it. Here's my code:

```
class Student{
public:
    string subject;
    Student(string _subject){
        subject = _subject;
    }
};
```

And here's my LinkedList template code

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList{

private:
    struct Node{
        Node *next;
        T value;
    };
    Node *root;
    Node *curr;
    int count;

public:
    LinkedList() : count(0), root(NULL){}
    void add(T val){
        if (root == NULL){
            root = new Node;
            root->value = val;
            root->next = NULL;
            curr = root;
        }
        else{
            curr->next = new Node;
            curr = curr->next;
            curr->value = val;
            curr->next = NULL;
        }
        count++;
    }

    void print(){
        for (Node *itr=root; itr != NULL; itr = itr->next){
            cout << itr->value << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    LinkedList<Student> a;
    Student sam("Math");
    a.add(sam)
}
```

When I run it, I get

> linkedlist.cpp: In constructor ‘LinkedList::Node::Node()’:
>   linkedlist.cpp:27:   instantiated from ‘void LinkedList::add(T) [with T = Student]’
>
> linkedlist.cpp:133:   instantiated from here
>
> linkedlist.cpp:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘Student::Student()’
>   linkedlist.cpp:18: note: candidates are: Student::Student(std::string)
>
> linkedlist.cpp:15: note:                 Student::Student(const Student&)
>   linkedlist.cpp: In member function ‘void LinkedList::add(T) [with T = Student]’:
>
> linkedlist.cpp:40: note: synthesized method ‘LinkedList::Node::Node()’ first required here

I have no clue what that error really means, and what it's asking me to do. If I do this instead:

```
int main(){
    LinkedList<Student*> a;
    Student sam("Math");
    a.add(&sam);
}
```

It works just fine.

But storing references to objects is not what I'm after. How can I get my LinkedList to make copies of the object I wish to add to it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all...

```
#include <utility>
```

Now, change this...

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    T     value;
};
```

For...

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    T     value;

    inline Node(const T &value) : value(value), next(nullptr) {}
    inline Node(T &&value) : value(std::move(value)), next(nullptr) {}
};
```

And, this...

```
void add(T val) {
    if(this->root == nullptr) {
        this->root = new Node;
        this->root->value = val;
        root->next = NULL;
        curr = root;
    } else {
        curr->next = new Node;
        curr = curr->next;
        curr->value = val;
        curr->next = NULL;
    }

    count++;
}
```

For this...

```
void add(const T &val){
    if(this->root == nullptr) {
        this->root = new Node(val);
        this->curr = root;
    } else {
        this->curr->next = new Node(val);
        this->curr = this->curr->next;
    }

    this->count++;
}

void add(T &&val){
    if(this->root == nullptr) {
        this->root = new Node(std::move(val));
        this->curr = root;
    } else {
        this->curr->next = new Node(std::move(val));
        this->curr = this->curr->next;
    }

    this->count++;
}
```

What happens is that you're creating a `Node` object with `new Node` with it's implicit default constructor. That implies that the default constructor for `Node::value` is called. Then, can you tell me if there's any? No. `Student` does not have a default constructor, so this won't work.

BTW, I made some minor redesigns to your code, so to avoid several issues that appeared by the way. As a bonus, you can now use move semantics (try `list.add(Student("Joe"))`)!

Also, remember to initialize `curr` to `nullptr` in the constructor initialization list!

Comment: Thank you very much! With a few edits, I'm humming along. However, using "&&" throws an error - "error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token".  What do you think is the problem?

Comment: @habudu: Are you using a *non*-C++11 conformant compiler? That `&&` is a C++11 feature, and compiling in C++98 or C++03 mode won't do the trick.

Comment: @habudu: **Edit**: Apparently (I noticed this from your error messages), you're using either GCC or Clang. Try passing `-std=c++11` in the command line then.

Answer (score 0):

Student must provide a default constructor. Try that:

```
Student(string _subject = "")
```

Because when you do `new Node` it creates a `Node` object, so it creates the `Node*` and `T` attributes of the `Node` class. And if `T` class has no default constructor, the compiler does not know how to create the object.

That's what the error message says:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Student::Student()’ linkedlist.cpp:18: note: candidates are: Student::Student(std::string)
```

It cannot find a default constructor `Student::Student()`, it only found one taking a string as argument `Student::Student(std::string)`

Comment: Downvoter, please elaborate. This definitely answers the question!